# any way to coloring the identical neighbor cells in excel?

Tags: excel

I am trying to apply the conditional formatting to an array (150 rows, 4 columns) to color the identical neighbor cells along each column. On each column, there will be some consecutive cells carry the same values, for example, on 1st column, I have

B
B
C
D
C
E
E
E
P
P
P
E

I want to color those consecutive cells such that 3 neighbors are the same. So EEE and PPP in above example will be highlight. I am using the conditional formatting "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" and I input the following expression

="AND(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()))=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()-1)), INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()))=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(), COLUMN()+1)))"

But it doesn't work. Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe three rules (all the same) applied to different ranges, say:

```
=AND(A1=A2,A1=A3)
```

Applies to:

```
=$A$1:$A$150
=$A$2:$A$150  
=$A$3:$A$150
```

Answer (score 0):

I would chop this up into three helper columns to make this more manageable.  Then use a final helper column to set the conditional format.

That is, the first helper column checks `=AND(This Cell = Above Cell, This Cell = Below Cell)`.
The second helper checks `=IF(Cell Below Me Is TRUE, Tag "ME" as TRUE)`.
And the third helper checks `=IF(Cell Above Me Is TRUE, Tag "ME" as TRUE)`.

Finally, the fourth helper is just an `OR` formula across the three helpers.  In my example, I'd simply set my Conditional Formatting rule to be `=E2` for cells `A2:A13`.

[image: Pic01]

[image: Pic02]

[image: Pic03]

[image: Pic04]

[image: Results]